# Formal proof for closed set.

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that for $K = Z \cap E \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ with:

$Z = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2 = 1 \}$ and

$E = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x+z = 0 \}$

the set K is closed. Now I know and can use that the intersection of closed sets is closed, which would leave me with proving that $E$ and $Z$ are closed. Isn't it enough to state that the two sets obviously contain their border because of the equality in the restriction?

---

Edit: Sorry for the confusion, the original title asking for proof of open set was wrong, since I'm trying to prove that the set is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $Z$ and $E$ are closed sets, $K$ is closed too. The set $Z$ is closed since $Z=f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)$, where $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$ and $f$ is continuous. And $E$ is closed for a similar reason.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, I just changed the question because the use of "open" was a mix-up, I'm sorry for the confusion. I was trying to prove the set is closed.

Comment: And I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just so that I can better understand the proof you provided: how can I verify that $Z$ is indeed equal to $f^{-1}(\{1\})$? And is my proof using the ball wrong, or is it even a proof? Thank you.

Comment: By definition,$$f^{-1}\bigl(\{1\}\bigr)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid f(x,y,z)=1\}$$and$$\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid f(x,y,z)=1\}=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\mid x^2+y^2=1\}=Z.$$I cannot comment your proof since I do not understand it.

Comment: Hey, I went looking but couldn't find which property you are using for your proof. Could you explain why from it $f(\{1\}) = Z$ follows that Z is closed?

Comment: Oh, I think I found it. Is it that $f$ is continuous $\Leftrightarrow$ $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed for all closed sets $A$? Do you know how I could prove that?

Comment: Yes, it is that property. It is a standard theorem in Topology.

Comment: Just out of interest, if I were to provide the same proof for $Z = \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x^2+y^2 \leq 3 \}$, would I just say that $f^{-1}([-3, 3]) = Z$ and finish the same way?

Comment: That is correct, although I would use $(-\infty,3]$ instead of $[-3,3]$. But it is just a matter of taste.